# terse code for comparing 4 numbers

Tags: c, math, coding-style, xor

I've to compare 4 variables `a,b,c,d` if any of them is `-1` return `false`.
and How mush terse this could be ?
may be some mathematical operation could be done !! I dont like wasting so many characters or lines for this simple thing.

Comment: You want to simplify `a==-1 && b==-1 && c==-1 && d==-1`?

Comment: Compare 4 variables `a,b,c,d` with what exactly?

Comment: erxtreamly sorry there was a typo in Question. I meant if any of them **is** -1 return false

Comment: tip: avoid using *clever* code, especially if somebody else wrote it for you :)

Comment: You have a simple, straight-forward implementation of what you want.  "I don't like wasting so many characters or lines for this simple thing" has to be about the worst reason to try to come up with a non-obvious alternative.  All you're going to do is let some corner case bug creep in and/or make it so the next person who looks at the code is left wondering WTF.

Answer (score 10):

Normally:

```
return a!=-1 && b!=-1 && c!=-1 && d!=-1;
```

---

Since `~(-1) == 0` in 2's complement machine, and `0` is a false value, we could reduce the above to

```
return ~a && ~b && ~c && ~d;
```

or, not relying on 2's complement:

```
return a+1 && b+1 && c+1 && d+1;
```

but it has undefined behavior on overflow.

(But please use the normal way. You may forget what this clever hack is doing years later.)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `return ((~a & ~b & ~c & ~d) < 0);` ? :)

Comment: Python says SyntaxError on `~(85) && ~(65)`

Comment: @NeelBasu: But the tag says "c", not Python.

Comment: Ya I was just giving a quick run. and I was afraid.

Comment: If `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` are signed ints, the overflow that can be caused by the "not relying on 2's complement" version is undefined. If they are of a signed integral type smaller than `int`, it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

If your numbers can be either non-negative or -1, then you can use the following:

```
return~(a|b|c|d);
```

(removed the white-space so it looks more terse)